# Visualizing double points.

Tags: geometry, soft-question, intuition, curves, visualization

I was trying to visualize by drawing  a curve / figure to get a double point on a curve. As per the [Wolfram article](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DoublePoint.html),  a double point is a point traced out twice as a closed curve is traversed.

Any visualization insights, intuition, figures of a double point would be much helpful.

Answer (score 1):

"8" and "$\infty$".  "$" has three.

And the graph of $y^2 = x^3 - 3x+2$ has one at $(1,0)$.
[image: Elliptic curve self-intersection]

Why not $r = \cos^2(\theta)$ in polar coordinates?
[image: Polar plot]

Comment: Nice!! how about an explicit expression of a closed curve having double points?, as I see the above is an open curve having double points

Comment: Why not use the obvious graph transformation $x \mapsto 1-x^2, y \mapsto y^2$ to get a closed curve with a single double point at the origin?

Comment: Nice one, I was thinking how to draw this graph transformation